# Error while writing video in OpenCV3 with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I was running a simple program on reading a video file (.mp4 format) and writing it back after inverting every frame. I get an error and a bug warning.

`BUG: The current event queue and the main event queue are not the same. Events will not be handled correctly. This is probably because _TSGetMainThread was called for the first time off the main thread.`

`Error in CoreDragRemoveTrackingHandler: -1856`

I am using El Captain OSX , I have installed python virtual environment to use Python 3.5 with OpenCV 3.2.0-rc. Can somebody help me with this.?

Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('Root.mp4')
# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'AVRN')
#out = cv2.VideoWriter('Root1.mp4',fourcc, 20.0, (640,360))
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'MJPG')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('Root1.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,360))
while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret==True:
        frame = cv2.flip(frame,0)

        # write the flipped frame
        out.write(frame)

        cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: alway put text instead of screenshot - now nobody can copy-paste your code to test it and make modifications.

Comment: ok. thanks. I will change it

Comment: maybe ask on [OpenCV issues](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be fixed by reinstalling opencv3 with --with-ffmpeg flag.

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/7474

Answer (score 0):

One thing i can tell you, there is no problem in the script you mentioned above :p, it is running fine on my system. Reinstall opencv and python in new virtual environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
fps = 15
capSize = (1280, 720)
#print cap.get(3)
#print cap.get(4)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('m', 'p', '4', 'v')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.mov',fourcc, fps, capSize, True)
```

It works for me, so I hope it helps you!